# SQL get total amount of Column with group by?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below you can see my SQL query

```
select c.email_address,o.order_id as "Number of Orders",
((oi.item_price-oi.discount_amount)*oi.quantity) as "Total amount" 
from customers c 
        inner join orders o on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
        inner join order_items oi on o.order_id=oi.order_id
```

From that, I can get output like below

```
Email            Orders_id  Amount
allan@yahoo.com     1       839.3
barryz@gmail.com    2       303.79
allan@yahoo.com     3       1208.16
allan@yahoo.com     3       253.15
chrisb@gmail.com    4       1678.6
david@hotmail.com   5       299
erinv@gmail.com     6       299
frank@gmail.com     7       489.3
frank@gmail.com     7       559.9
frank@gmail.com     7       489.99
garyz@yahoo.com     8       679.99
david@hotmail.com   9       489.3
```

But I want to customize it like below

```
Email           Number of Orders    Total Amount
allan@yahoo.com         3            2300.61
barryz@gmail.com        1            303.79
chrisb@gmail.com        1            1678.6
david@hotmail.com       2            788.3
erinv@gmail.com         1            299
frank@gmail.com         3            1539.19
garyz@yahoo.com         1            679.99
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the question, use `GROUP BY` and aggregate the number of orders and the total:

```sql
select c.email_address,
       COUNT(o.order_id) as "Number of Orders",
       SUM((oi.item_price-oi.discount_amount)*oi.quantity) as "Total amount" 
from   customers c 
       inner join orders o on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
       inner join order_items oi on o.order_id=oi.order_id
GROUP BY c.email_address
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your query:

```
select email_address, count("Number of Orders") as number_of_orders, sum("Total Amount") as amount
from (
    select c.email_address,o.order_id as "Number of Orders",
    ((oi.item_price-oi.discount_amount)*oi.quantity) as "Total amount" 
    from customers c 
        inner join orders o on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
        inner join order_items oi on o.order_id=oi.order_id
    )Z
group by email
```

Comment: If you have a quoted identifier (i.e. `"Number of Orders"` or `"Total amount"`) in the inner query then you need to use exactly the same quoted identifier (including the quotes and the same case) in the outer query. Also, the outer query cannot use the `order_id` column as it is not in the `SELECT` clause of the inner query, you would need to use the alias instead.

Comment: Thank you both, fixed and noted for future. Tried to upvote @MT0 but I don't have enough rep to upvote yet.